# In a finite ring extension there are only finitely many prime ideals lying over a given prime ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm trying to solve the exercise 6.7 of Miles Reid's *Undergraduate Commutative Algebra* (pag 93).

> How can I prove that if $B$ is a finite ring extension of $A$, there are only finitely many prime ideals of $B$ whose intersection with $A$ is a given prime ideal of $A$?

Thank you!

Comment: This is also the exercise 9.3 in Matsumura, *Commutative Ring Theory*.

Comment: You'll possibly need this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46654

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: Let $\mathfrak{p} \subset A$ be a prime ideal. Localize at $\mathfrak{p}$, so that $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a local ring. The primes $\mathfrak{q}$ in $B$ for which $\mathfrak{q} \cap A = \mathfrak{p}$ are called 
**primes lying over $\mathfrak{p}$**. The primes lying over $\mathfrak{p}$ remain in the ring $B_{\mathfrak{p}},$ and are distinct. All these primes lie over the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ in $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$, so they are all maximal. Now, how many maximal ideals containing $\mathfrak{p}B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ can $B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ have?

Comment: I was trying to prove that $B_p/pB_p$ is an Artinian Ring, so it has a finite number of maximal ideals. Hence $B_p$ has only finitely many maximal ideals containing $pB_p$. Is this the right way?

Comment: Could you suggest me a way to prove that $B_p/pB_p$ is Artinian?

Comment: Thank you very much, I should have seen it by myself but I'm not very familiar with Artinian rings. Very useful!

Comment: Could you explain how "all these primes lie over $\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$" implies that they are all maximal, and how that implies that they contain $\mathfrak{p}B_\mathfrak{p}$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** First show that it's enough to prove this for maximal $\mathfrak p$ (localize).  Then show that it's enough to prove this when the maximal ideal is $(0)$ (factor). Then you have a finite $k$-algebra and must show that it has finitely many prime ideals.