# Can infinitely many primes lie over a prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, integral-domain

> Let $R \subset S$ be an integral extension of domains and $\mathfrak p \subset R$ a prime ideal. Can it be the case that there are infinitely many distinct primes ${\cal P} \subset S$ such that ${\cal P} \cap R=\mathfrak p$?

Certainly this is impossible if $S$ is a Dedekind domain, because the primes lying over $\mathfrak p$ are the primes of $S$ occurring in the factorization of $\mathfrak p$ over $S$.  I don't have much of an intuition for integral ring extensions that aren't number fields, so past this I'm not particularly sure.

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-finite_morphism

Comment: If $S$ is Noetherian, then there are only finitely many primes lying over a given prime. (This is claimed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542892/r-subseteq-s-integral-extension-and-s-noetherian-implies-r-noetherian) and can be proved by using similar arguments of those given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270428/exercise-6-7-of-miles-reids-undergraduate-commutative-algebra).)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer is yes.

Consider $\mathbb{Z} \subset S$, where $S$ is the ring of all the algebraic integers in $\mathbb{C}$. This is by definition integral, and for a fixed prime $p\in\mathbb Z$, one can find a sequence of Galois extensions $L_i/\mathbb{Q}$ such that $g_i(p) \to \infty$, where $g_i(p)$ is the number of primes of $L_i$ lying above $p$. (Using cyclotomic extensions suffice.) As each of these $g_i(p)$ primes can be further lifted up to distinct primes in $S$, this shows that there are infinitely many primes in $S$ lying above $p$.

**Why cyclotomic extensions have arbitrarily large number of primes lying above a fixed $p$**?

Consider $L = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$. Take $n$ that is not divisible by $p$, then $e(p) = 1$ in this extension. $f(p)$ is the order of Frobenius, which in this case is the smallest positive integer $f$ such that $n \mid p^f - 1$, and $g(p) = \phi(n)/f$. So everything would work if $n$ is large and $f$ is small. So take any $f$, and let $n = p^f - 1$, then $\frac{\phi(p^f-1)}{f} \to \infty$ as $f \to \infty$.

Comment: I was thinking about $\mathbb Z$ into the algebraic integers. Is there an easy reason, or do you have a reference for why Cyclotomic extensions work? So for instance we could replace the algebraic integers, by integral closure of $\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb Q^{ab}$? (Also I was asking if it was possible for an infinite number of primes to lie over, so the answer is yes).

Comment: @JacobSchlather Oh, sorry for mixing up the yes's and no's. I will add some details about cyclotomic extensions part.