# Number of maximal ideals in integral extension S over R (Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra, chapter 15.3, corollary 27)

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> $\space$Suppose $R$ is a subring of the ring  $S$ with $1\in R$ and assume $S$ is integral and finitely generated (as a ring) over R. If $P$ is a maximal ideal in $R$ then there is a nonzero and finite number of maximal ideals $Q$ of $S$ with $Q\cap R = P$.

$\space$I'm working on the verification of above corollary (Dummit and Foote, Abstract Algebra, p. 695).

$\space$In the proof described in the text, authors say "To prove that there are only finitely many possible $Q$ it suffices to prove that there are only finitely many homomorphism from $S$ to a field containing $R/P$ that extend the homomorphism from $R$ to $R/P$.", however, I can't understand the reason why this approach works.

$\space$Of course, for each maximal ideal $Q$, we can construct homomorphism from $S$ to $S/Q$ ,which is a field containing $R/P$, by natural projection. And $S/Q$ is isomorphic to one of the field extension of the form $(R/P)[\overline s_1,\overline s_2....,\overline s_n]$, and possible extension of such form is finitlely many.

$\space$ If $Q_1 \neq Q_2$ implies $S/Q_1 \ncong S/Q_2$ we have done. However, I can't prove this, and intuitively, it possibly be false...
 Could anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: I read your post, as well as the solution by Moos. I just have one question. Why are there finitely many possible field extensions of the form you described?

Comment: @Malkoun Let me edit my answer.

Comment: @Moos: your edited answer now makes complete sense to me, thank you.

Comment: I know that what you want is to see how works a particular proof, but a more direct approach can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753042/finitely-many-prime-ideals-lying-over-mathfrakp).

Comment: Thank you very much for useful information!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not really grasped which set exactly the authors claim to be finite. Let me spell it out.

Consider the set of pairs $(K,p)$ where $K$ is a field and $p$ an epimorphism $S \to K$, such that the composition $P \to R \to S \to K$ is zero.

First claim: This set is finite.

Second claim: This proves the desired statement. Let me proof this. Clearly any maximal ideal $Q$ with $Q \cap R = P$ yields such a pair $(S/Q,p)$ where $p$ is the projection $S \to S/Q$. And its also clear that different $Q$'s will yield different pairs, simply by the fact that $Q$ is the kernel of $p$, i.e. different $Q$'s yield different $p$'s.

Hence the set of such $Q$'s is smaller than the set of such pairs. So it suffices to prove the first claim, which you have already done.

---

Let me also proof the first claim, that there are finitely many pairs $(K,p)$: Let $s \in S$. Then we have a monic equation
$$s^n+r_{n-1}s^{n-1}+ \dotsb + r_0=0.$$
Apply $p$ to get 
$$0=p(s)^n + p(r_{n-1})p(s)^{n-1} + \dotsb + p(r_0)$$
and note that for any $r \in R$, we have $p(r) = \overline r$, where $\overline r$ is the residue class in $R/P$, since $R \to S \to K$ factors over $R/P$.

Thus we have an equation

$$0=p(s)^n + \overline{r_{n-1}}p(s)^{n-1} + \dotsb + \overline{r_{0}},$$
which means that there are only finitely many choices for $p(s)$, namely at most the roots of this polynomial in $R/P[X]$.

Since $S$ is finitely generated over $R$, $p$ is uniquely determined by the images of the finitely many generators. We have just shown that each generator has only finitely many possibly images, so there only finitely many choices for $p$.

Comment: Aah, very nice argument, thank you!

Comment: Thank you sooo much for informative suggestion and beautiful proof!  Now, I understand!