# Uniqueness of extensions of prime ideals in integral rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

I'll first state some theorems

**Corollary 5.9 [Atiyah-Macdonald pg. 61]** Let $A \subset B $ be rings, $B$ integral over $A$. Let $q,q'$ be prime ideals in $B$, such that $q\subset q'$. If $q^c=q'^c=p$, then $q = q'$.

**Theorem 5.10 [Atiyah-Macdonald pg.62]** Let $A \subset B$ be rings, $B$ integral over $A$, and let $p$ be a prime ideal of $A$. Then there exists a prime ideal $q$ of $B$ such that $q\cap A = q^c = p$.

My question is that, can I somehow combine the above two theorems to conclude the following:

> If $A \subset B$ are rings, $B$ integral over $A$. Then for every prime ideal $p \subset A$, there is a unique prime ideal $q \subset B$ such that $q \cap A = p$.

One might proceed as follows: "by **Theorem 5.10**, there is atleast one $q$ such that $q \cap A = p$. If $q'$ also satisfies $q' \cap A = p$, then..."

But to use **Corollary 5.9**, I either need to show that $q \subset q'$ or $q' \subset q$. Both of which are not "natural". So is this true or is there a counterexample?

Comment: Theorem 5.10 says that the contraction map $\mathrm{Spec}(B) \to \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is surjective, but Corollary 5.9 does not say that the contraction map is injective, but instead that it reflects the property of an inclusion of prime ideals being an equality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not true. There are many counterexamples. In fact, there can even be infinitely many primes in $B$ lying over a given prime in $A$, as shown here: [Can infinitely many primes lie over a prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296428/can-infinitely-many-primes-lie-over-a-prime).

Here is an example which I used recently (for another related purpose in an assignment). Let $k$ be a field. Consider the ring homomorphism $k\lbrack t\rbrack\to k\lbrack x,y\rbrack /(xy)$ with $t\mapsto x+y$ (or alternatively, the inclusion $k\lbrack x + y\rbrack\subset k\lbrack x,y\rbrack /(xy)$). This map is integral because $x^2 - x(x+y)=0$ in $k\lbrack x,y\rbrack /(xy)$ and symmetrically for $y$. But in $k\lbrack t\rbrack$, the maximal ideal $(t+1)$ has both $(x,y+1)$ and $(x+1,y)$ lying over it. In case you know some algebraic geometry, here is a visualization of the map at the level of varieties:

[image]

The ring $k\lbrack x,y\rbrack /(xy)$ corresponds to the union of the coordinate axes, whereas $k\lbrack t\rbrack$ is the red affine line in the drawing. The squiggly arrows indicates the map of varieties corresponding to the map of algebras I gave. Note how every point (maximal ideal) along the red line has two points (maximal ideals) lying over it -- except for the point at the origin.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very nice answer so +1!